# Answerers should not be able to vote for any other answer, of the same question

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, tactical-downvoting

I decided to make my point today, but have had this thought for quite some time.

Anyone answering a question should not be able to cast a +1 or -1 vote for any of the other answers of that same question.

In case the answer is posted *after* the vote happened, that vote should be nullified.

(In case the answer is deleted, same restriction).

Besides, it's related but not the main reason, the following is doable...

- A makes an answer and gets a +1
- B makes an answer after, and is at 0, their answer appears at the bottom
- B downvote A for a few minutes to be at the same level
- B, then, retracts their downvote, after their answer has been upvoted (same level again)

Not really fair...

Comment: To me it seems this would cause more harm than good. If I come across an old question with a terrible/wrong answer I'd have to choose between signalling low quality content or contributing better content when ideally I'd like to do both. It seems this would only be useful in FGITW situations where people are rushing to answer low hanging fruit which very often turn out to be duplicates or off-topic in the first place.

Comment: There are so many other people just voting, not answering, if your answer is better than the wrong one, it'll be upvoted, the other one will be downvoted. There is something just wrong with being judge and gone...

Comment: It won't make much difference to those who downvote all other answers - they will just use s puppet to downvote, after all, they are already immoral, so why not?

Comment: You can only retract your vote within the 5 minute grace period. You need to be pretty persistent to get that scheme payout. I normally just leave the tactical downvote and move on ...

Comment: @MartinJames Having a puppet account used all the time along with the main one would be detected probably.

Comment: @rene Answering and voting appears to me as being judge and gone. Of course we are used to that behavior for so long, but the "slashdot" approach (no vote if you post, per thread) seems more fair, to me. (slashdot is not a Q&A site, but the principle is the same).

Comment: But as you just said, if the other answer is better it will be upvoted over time anyway?

Comment: It depends on for whose "fair" you're catering for. I think it is fair to future visitors to let them know an answer is subpar. If that happens to be on a question I wrote an answer so be it. "nullifying" for those few cases where low-life thinks tactical voting helps them is a waste of time and resource. The vote correction will be negligible in the grand-scheme of voting. Specially if you give it 6 to 8 years.

Comment: "In case the answer is posted after the vote happened, that vote should be nullified." this does not make sense. You can't vote on an answer before it is posted.

Comment: @DavidPostill: I assume the point is if you vote on answer X and then post your own answer Y, your vote on X is nullified. (I vehemently disagree with the idea, but that timing part is at least consistent.)

Comment: @JonSkeet OK, that makes sense.

Comment: Ok, -18 (and counting), the feature might not be implemented ;-)

Comment: Is...this really a problem right now?

Comment: Why the B has to rectract his downvote? he could stay at the top.

Comment: @TemaniAfif if they don't remove the down votes they lose points and it no longer [tactical-downvote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tactical-downvoting)... They also may have posted essentially identical answer and if the same approach shows positive and negative votes people reading in the future may be concerned if something really wrong with higher voted question. So removing tactical downvote is pretty much required for this strategy to pay out.

Answer (score 25):

Votes are quality control for all the people reading the answers. We should have as much signalling as possible to all the people that are looking for an answer to their problem and don't know which to choose. We should waste their time as little as possible with trying flawed answers and direct them to the good ones.

And if I'm a subject matter expert and can answer the question, why shouldn't I also contribute to that quality control? My view is likely better than most when it comes to evaluating answers. Or why should I be put off from answering until everyone else has answered so I can still vote. We want to see good answers as soon as possible.

I write an answer, so does someone else shortly after and I think the other answer is wrong or provides bad advice. All I can do now is comment.

Equally if I see an answer and it's better than mine, maybe it covers some point I missed, why can't I upvote it? We even have a [sportsmanship badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/805/sportsmanship) to encourage doing just that.

Answer (score 13):

That's a terrible idea.

As a subject matter expert if I post an answer and then I see another answer, which I know is wrong or provides worse recommendation I must downvote it. If I can answer the question I should be able to also vote on other answers. After all, if I was able to answer it I think I know something about the topic to decide if the other answer is good or bad.

Same thing when I post an answer and someone posts an even better answer. I would like to upvote their contribution too. If both of our answers are good then I don't care that the other answer has +5 and I have +2. The outcome I wanted was achieved and exceeded. Not only I posted a good answer, someone else posted another good answer, too. I am happy for such an outcome.

The shady practise you describe is not common, but the system allows it. However, I really do not care about it. I often post answers to questions years old. Many of my answers have 0 score. The only thing that bugs me is when there is highly upvoted answer on an old question which is wrong, and when I post a correct answer it gets barely any attention. But your suggestion doesn't help with that at all.